# What is the fastest way to move a 720 ton statue for a distance of 500 km from Cairo to Luxor with modern technology?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, transportation

The ancient egyptians could do it but we don't know how long it took them.
What would be the fastest way to do it with modern technology? How long would it take?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colossi_of_Memnon

[image: colossi of memnon]

[image: distance-cairo-to-luxor-400km]

Comment: Very carefully.

Comment: `how would you do ....?`  is a question that asks for an opinion ... such questions are off topic here, especially since there is no constraint stated ... `I'd cut it into pieces and transport by camel` is not a wrong answer ... any answer is "correct", that's why the question is not allowed

Comment: I don't think this is good enough for an answer but the Nile is navigable to shipping from the Mediterranean to the Aswan dam which is south of Luxor. (Source: [Improve Sailing](https://improvesailing.com/destinations/how-far-can-you-sail-up-the-nile#:~:text=500%2D600%20miles&text=In%20the%20lower%20Nile%2C%20from,rocky%2C%20making%20navigation%20more%20difficult.).) There would be some obvious advantages in less onerous height restrictions and increased maximum block weight with short specialist road trips at each end.

Comment: Get a pair of Belaz 75710s .  Drop the dump bodies and fabricate a carriage that weighs less than 170 tons. Oh, you wanted the fastest way - Chain a couple more up as tractors. Might need some permits.

Comment: Even 50 years ago, it was fairly routine to move 2 and 3 story houses that weighed on the order of 300-500 tons. They're moved quite slowly, but a lot of that is that houses aren't built to withstand any significant acceleration. These are almost certainly a lot less fragile. If you had a smooth road in between, probably figure something like a week. Without a road, you'd have to look pretty carefully at the terrain to even come up with even a rough guess at time.